# How to use Cache in Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, caching, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

its quite a simple problem, but I am unable to get over with it.

What I want to do is , I have an ImageView and I want to set an image on it using UIL, which I am able to do well. My another need is that:

each time the activity/fragment is started, it shlould show the previous loaded image corresponding to a particular URL, untill it downloads the new one. So basically, I want to cache the image, and show the cached image everytime.

My Initialization code:

```
    DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stubimage)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.imptyURL)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.failed).build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration configs = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .memoryCacheSize(41943040).defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions)
            .discCacheSize(104857600)
            .threadPoolSize(10).build();

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(configs);
```

I did some digging and found some code, which eventually is not working and is as follows:
**My Usage Code:**

```
    String URL2="http://asset0.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/02/13/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_35117983_28_610x458.jpg";

    ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    List<String> memCache = MemoryCacheUtil.findCacheKeysForImageUri(URL2, loader.getMemoryCache());
    boolean cacheFound = !memCache.isEmpty();
    if (!cacheFound) {
        File discCache = DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(URL2, loader.getDiscCache());
        if (discCache != null) {
            cacheFound = discCache.exists();
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "memCache:"+cacheFound, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache().get(URL2) != null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "something is there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing is there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(URL2, (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
```

**Referenced Questions:**

[Universal Image Loader cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443810/universal-image-loader-cache)